# Re-using programmatically created Textviews

Tags: java, android

I've written code to perform a search and display the results below the search form in the XML file.

However, by creating TextViews dynamically, it keeps adding more TextViews so the number of TextViews increases by 5 everytime I perform a search. How could I re-use the TextViews so I can update the text to be displayed rather than creating more TextViews?

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {

    TextView altName = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    altName.setText("blah");
    altName.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
    altName.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.textSize);

    TableRow altNameTr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    altNameTr.addView(altName);
    table.addView(altNameTr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Before search you create TextViews and add them to the table. Don't forget to store them (`ArrayList<TextView>` would work fine)
2. Every time you have your search results, go through your TextViews list and update them accordingly (with `setText()`)

So your code should like:

```
public class Search
{
    ArrayList<TextView> results = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    public void init(Context context)
    {
        TableRow altNameTr = new TableRow(context);
        TextView tv;

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            tv = new TextView(context);
            results.add(tv);
            altNameTr.addView(tv);
        }
        table.addView(altNameTr);
    }

    public void fillSearchResults()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<results.size(); i++) 
        {
            results.get(i).setText("Whatever you need to set here"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** When you create your **TextView Dynamically**, assign **ids to them using** `setId(int i)` **method.**

**2. Reuse the TextView using their**`ids`**whereever u need them..**

Comment: You can also use:

`public void setTag (Object tag)` 
Since: API Level 1

"Sets the tag associated with this view. A tag can be used to mark a view in its hierarchy and does not have to be unique within the hierarchy. Tags can also be used to store data within a view without resorting to another data structure."

Answer (score 1):

In your function as first line you can add `table.removeAllViews()`. 
This way your table always gets cleared out before performing a new search.

If you allways have 5 results, then it's better to use Pavel Dudka's method :)